# Stop browser from asking user if they do want to refresh the page

Tags: php, html, css

I have a function where a user selects a page number from a drop down list, and it submits the result to the same page, so whatever was selected can remain selected, and it works, but if a user tries to refresh the page, it'll ask if the user want to resubmit the form.

Is there a way to stop the browser from asking the user if they want to refresh the page?

```
function select($pages,$location) {

    echo "<form method='POST' action='$location'>";
    echo "<select name='select' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";

    while ($tempCount < $pages) {
        $tempCount++;

        if ($_POST['select'] != null && $_POST['select'] == $tempCount) {
        $selected = "selected"; 
    }
    else {
        $selected = null;
    }

    echo "<option $selected value='$tempCount'>Page $tempCount</option>";

    }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</form>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Might be somewhat helpful:http://www.satya-weblog.com/2009/10/avoid-resubmitting-html-form.html

Comment: I believe it's browser related that it asks if the user wants to resubmit the form. What it means is that the browser sees that your last page was a POST request, and so if you would refresh, then that means you send the post details again, for that reason you get the popup. A way to get around it is to use redirect, like Jacob Gray mentioned with the link. So header('location: ..........'); Other way would be stepping away from post and use get, by doing <form method="get">

Comment: @Verkade89 Are there any significant differences from POST and GET, other than that?

Comment: @Verkade89 Very good answer about using the GET method. It works like a charm. ;P

Comment: Well, POST is best if users can post a lot of information, or if you have to fill in anything with a password. You do not want the password to be seen in the address bar of course. GET is limited to certain amount of characters as far as I know, about 2000 I believe. But if you post a single number, then you can use GET without a problem. In your case, I believe you want to give people the option to skip many pages ahead by a select input, and in this situation, GET is pretty much the best. Also if you have previous/next page links, in <a>, well, they make use of GET as well.

Comment: @frosty Hard to detail in a comment, but very different forms of HTTP calls. GET and most other methods (of which you see little) are like "Tell me the latest stock prices." POST is like "Here is a new stock purchase I would like to make. <data> When you've finished processing it, tell me the latest stock prices." It's common to redirect a POST page to a GET page, so that the browser knows how to re-fetch the page. Generally, GET should not change state - POST usually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three possible solutions.

1. Use GET instead of POST.  The browser won't prompt the user for a GET.
2. Use a POST, but post the data to an interstitial ("in between") page (or even just an http handler) which never renders.  The interstitial should process the posted data then redirect to a real page which is displayed to the user.  Because every redirect is a GET, refreshing that final page won't trigger the prompt.
3. Use neither GET nor POST.  Instead, update what you need behind the scenes using AJAX.

Comment: It's worth noting that GET is unsuitable for server operations that change server state. I don't think that applies here though, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use POST, you can use a GET form as suggested in the comments. But the usual way of solving this is by applying the [POST/Redirect/GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. Unfortunately it means you will have to manually pass the data around.

Another hacky and not fool-proof way is to listen for the F5 key press and then do `window.location = window.location` in Javascript. The assignment will cause the page to reload without any warnings, but it doesn't work if the user presses the refresh button in the browser itself.